# Laravel has mysql error in ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

My code works fine in normal but when i use ajax i have problem to save multiple input i take this message

"SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'hotel_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `hotel_tour` (`hotel_id`, `tour_id`) values (5,2, 6))"

i use bootstrap select input 
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

View:

```
<tr>
        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'tour.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'id'=>'create-form','class'=>'form-horizontal row-border', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
        <td>{{--Hotel--}}
            {!! Form::select('hotel_id[]', $hotels, null,
            ['title' => trans('panel.hotels'),
             'id'=>'hotel_id','class'=>'select input-lg dropdown-toggle form-control',
             'multiple data-live-search="true"',])!!}
        </td>

        <td>{{--Two Bed --}}
            {!! Form::text('two_bed_price',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
        </td>

        <td>{{--One Bed --}}
            {!! Form::text('one_bed_price',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
        </td>

        <td>{{--Child With Bed --}}
            {!! Form::text('child_with_bed_price',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
        </td>

        <td>{{--Child No Bed --}}
            {!! Form::text('child_no_bed_price',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
        </td>



        <td> {{--Labels--}}
                {!! Form::select('label_id[]', $labels, null,
                ['title' => trans('panel.labels'),
                 'id'=>'label_id','class'=>'select input-lg dropdown-toggle form-control',
                 'multiple data-live-search="true"',
                ])!!}
        </td>

        <td>{{--Order--}}
            {!! Form::number('ordered',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
        </td>

        <td> {{--Status--}}
            {{-- get config from config file with config() function --}}
            {!! Form::select('status',config('system.status'),'published',['class' => 'form-control input-lg']) !!}
        </td>

        <td> {{--Submit & Cancel--}}
                {!!  Form::submit(trans('panel.submit'),['id'=>'create','class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-info'])!!}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a id="remove-tour" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">-</a>
        </td>

            {{--Package--}}
            {!! Form::hidden('package_id',$package->id)!!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </tr>
```

js:

```
        $("#create-form").on('submit', function(e){
        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        e.preventDefault(e);

        var url =  "{{route('tour.store')}}";

        var hotel_id = $('#hotel_id').val();
        var label_id = $('#label_id').val();

        var values = $(this).serialize() +'&hotel_id=' + hotel_id
                                         +'&label_id=' + label_id;


        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:url,
            data:values,
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN':_token
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){

            }
        });
    });
```

controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //Validation
    Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'package_id' => 'required|max:10|numeric',
        'hotel_id' => 'required|max:10',
        'status' => 'required|max:191',
    ])->validate();

    $data = array_add($request->all(), 'user_id', Auth::user()->id); //add user id to request

    //Save Item
    if ( $item =Tour::create($data)) {
        if(
            $item->hotels()->sync($request->input('hotel_id'))
        ) {
            $item->labels()->sync($request->input('label_id'));
            $url = route('tour.edit', ['id' => $item->id]);  //go to edit page
            $message = trans('message.item-created', ['item' => 'Tour']); //translate message
            Session::flash('message', $message);
            return redirect($url);
```

model

```
class Tour extends Model
{
protected $guarded = ['id','hotel_id','label_id'];
public $timestamps = false;

function package()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Package::class);
}

public function currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class);
}


public function labels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Label::class);
}

public function hotels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Hotel::class);
}
}
```

Comment: Your issue fix using "contentType: false and processData: false" or not ?

Comment: Unfortunately. no

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this code in your ajax object in jquery

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```